# Adding Points to existing attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, attribute-table, geocoding

I have a table of 150 records which I was able to geocode except for 21 points. I'm able to manually geocode the rest of these 21 points. Every time I add the point, it creates a new row (which I know is normal). Is it possible, however, to add the point to an existing row? I have 62 fields in my attribute table, so I'd like to avoid copy and pasting.

Here is what my table looks like (This is is a copy of my attribute table exported into excel):
[image]

So far, I've created a shapefile with all the the unmatched points plotted with an ID number as the only attribute. I was thinking that I could add the ID number to the my already geocoded data and join the two sets together.

Comment: Have you tried editing *existing* features instead of adding new ones? Please **edit** your question to explicitly describe your procedure. A screenshot or two wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made the ID numbers carefully to match the original shapefile, a [Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002q000000) can help (or [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) if you work in python). I recommend to use the [Export feature](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000t000000) after everything together.